# Is there a better pythonic way to rewrite the while loop?

Tags: python

I wrote this function to do the strStr function:

```
def strStr(haystack: str, needle: str) -> int:
    if not needle:
        return 0

    len_h = len(haystack)
    len_n = len(needle)

    if len_n > len_h:
        return -1

    index_h = 0
    index_n = 0
    matched_count = 0
    while index_h < len_h and index_n < len_n:
        v_h = haystack[index_h]
        v_n = needle[index_n]
        if v_h != v_n:
            index_h = index_h - matched_count + 1
            index_n = 0
            matched_count = 0
        else:
            index_h += 1
            index_n += 1
            matched_count += 1

        if index_n == len_n:
            return (index_h - len_n)

    return -1


print(strStr('hello', 'll'))
print(strStr('mississippi', 'issip'))
```

The while loop is the C or Java way. I tried to use for ... in range in Python. But failed to do it, because I need to update the indexes based on conditions. The for loop in Python doesn't seem to work. Still, is there a python way to replace the while loop?

Comment: The most Pythonic way would be haystack.find(needle) but I guess you know that. I'm sure there are plenty of tricks you could do to reduce the number of lines, but your code is pretty clear as it is so you cou;d argue it's most Pythonic to leave it simple.

Comment: There are lots of ways to do this better in Python -- down to just calling the appropriate string method. If you want to stick to a manual search, take a look at enumerate and string slicing -- there is no need to juggle Indizes and lengths yourself. Also take note that error codes are not Pythonic; raise an IndexError if there is no appropriate index.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python has a string method .find() that's implemented using the Boyer-Moore method (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boyer%E2%80%93Moore%E2%80%93Horspool_algorithm).

This contains a couple of while loops. So I would say it's a reasonably pythonic way to do it.